# How to access Carbon port offset from a webapp in AS

Tags: port, jax-rs, wso2, offset

Is there a way to access Carbon port offset from a war deployed in AS programatically?I want to generate the WSDL url of the deploying Jax-RS service.

Answer (score 0):

It is available as system property "portOffset".